# SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/ has not been defined

Tags: openshift, websphere-traditional

I have deployed WebSphere Traditional on RedHat OpenShift but I'm unable to get the admin console. I could see that the server is running inside the pod. Attaching the yaml files I have used and the pod logs that are generated. Please help. Thanks!

YAML Files for Pod and Service -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: was-traditional
    labels:
        app: websphere
spec:
    containers:
    - name: was-container
      image: ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.17

------------------------------------

apiVersion : v1
kind : Service
metadata :
  name : was-service
spec :
  selector :
    app : websphere
  type : NodePort
  ports :
    - protocol : TCP
      port : 9043
      targetPort : 9043
      nodePort : 31085
```

WAS Pod Logs -

```
{"type":"was_message","host":"was-traditional","ibm_cellName":"DefaultCell01","ibm_nodeName":"DefaultNode01","ibm_serverName":"server1","ibm_sequence":"1611228360189_0000000000113","message":"SRVE0255E: A WebGroup\/Virtual Host to handle \/ibm\/console\/ has not been defined.","ibm_datetime":"2021-01-21T11:26:00.189+0000","ibm_messageId":"SRVE0255E","ibm_methodName":"handleRequest","ibm_className":"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer","ibm_threadId":"0000006c","module":"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer","loglevel":"SEVERE"}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can `oc port-forward <pod> 9043:9043` on a workstation that needs to view the admin console then access it via localhost:9043.  It will not work with an alternate port due to how virtual hosting works in traditional websphere.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. I face the same issue on Kubernetes also. But it's working on Docker if I just run the docker run command and append /ibm/console in the URL Any suggestions? Thanks!