# SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /<context-name> has not been defined, when deployed on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, websphere, openshift-origin, websphere-traditional

I have deployed WebSphere Traditional on RedHat OpenShift but I'm unable to get the admin console and my application as well. I could see that the server is running inside the pod. Attaching the yaml files I have used and the pod logs that are generated. Please help.

YAML Files for Pod and Service -

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: was-traditional
    labels:
        app: websphere
spec:
    containers:
    - name: was-container
      image: ibmcom/websphere-traditional:latest
      
-------------------------------------------


apiVersion : v1
kind : Service
metadata :
  name : was-service
spec :
  selector :
    app : websphere
  type : ClusterIP
  ports :
    - protocol : TCP
      port : 9043
      targetPort : 9043
    - protocol : TCP
      port : 9080
      targetPort : 9080
```

Further, I have also exposed my service with route, under route I have given target-port as 9080 and my endpoint is was-service.apps.cluster.com.
When, I try to access admin console or my application, it  gives me error.

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle was-service.apps.cluster.com:80 is not being defined.

Comment: Is your application really deployed? Normally you would use an application image based on the base twas image not use it directly.

This behavior is normal for the admin console as it is only reachable on admin_host which is not exposed by any route.  You should use port-forwarding to connect directlly to the admin console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/ has not been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828084/srve0255e-a-webgroup-virtual-host-to-handle-ibm-console-has-not-been-defined)

Comment: No, actually I want to access my application through route purpose only so that load-balancing should happen through service. Any changes of context-name not configured properly.